# DHCP Requests out of line with lease time, inordinate amount of requests to server

Tags: dhcp, mac-osx-server, dhcp-server, osx-mountain-lion

Environment contains an OS X 10.6.8 Server with OS X 10.8.2 clients. DHCP is running on server with a lease time of 1 Day (86400 seconds). The system log is flooded with DHCP REQUEST/ACH messages logged every 2 hours (not the expected 1 day interval). See log "Server Log" below.

On the client side. I checked the contents of var/db/dhcpclient/leases for the en0 interface. This is the only interface enabled. The results are as expected. The LeaseLength key has a value of 85536 seconds (assuming it will decrement from the LeaseStartDate). See file "var/dv/dhcpclient/leases" below.

Any insight as to what might be causing this behavior would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Server Log:

```
2/27/13 10:00:17 PM bootpd[84012]   DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,d4:9a:20:d5:7a:9c <labmac36>
2/27/13 10:00:18 PM bootpd[84012]   ACK sent labmac36 192.168.6.67 pktsize 322
2/27/13 10:00:24 PM bootpd[84012]   DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,d4:9a:20:d5:7a:9c <labmac36>
2/27/13 10:00:24 PM bootpd[84012]   ACK sent labmac36 192.168.6.67 pktsize 322
2/27/13 10:00:25 PM bootpd[84012]   DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,d4:9a:20:d5:7a:9c <labmac36>
2/27/13 10:00:25 PM bootpd[84012]   ACK sent labmac36 192.168.6.67 pktsize 322
2/28/13 12:00:44 AM bootpd[85662]   DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,d4:9a:20:d5:7a:9c <labmac36>
2/28/13 12:00:44 AM bootpd[85662]   ACK sent labmac36 192.168.6.67 pktsize 322
2/28/13 12:00:51 AM bootpd[85662]   DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,d4:9a:20:d5:7a:9c <labmac36>
2/28/13 12:00:51 AM bootpd[85662]   ACK sent labmac36 192.168.6.67 pktsize 322
2/28/13 2:01:12 AM  bootpd[87335]   DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,d4:9a:20:d5:7a:9c <labmac36>
2/28/13 2:01:12 AM  bootpd[87335]   ACK sent labmac36 192.168.6.67 pktsize 322
2/28/13 2:01:18 AM  bootpd[87335]   DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,d4:9a:20:d5:7a:9c <labmac36>
2/28/13 2:01:18 AM  bootpd[87335]   ACK sent labmac36 192.168.6.67 pktsize 322
2/28/13 2:01:19 AM  bootpd[87335]   DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,d4:9a:20:d5:7a:9c <labmac36>
2/28/13 2:01:19 AM  bootpd[87335]   ACK sent labmac36 192.168.6.67 pktsize 322
2/28/13 4:01:39 AM  bootpd[89028]   DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,d4:9a:20:d5:7a:9c <labmac36>
2/28/13 4:01:39 AM  bootpd[89028]   ACK sent labmac36 192.168.6.67 pktsize 322
2/28/13 4:01:46 AM  bootpd[89028]   DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,d4:9a:20:d5:7a:9c <labmac36>
2/28/13 4:01:46 AM  bootpd[89028]   ACK sent labmac36 192.168.6.67 pktsize 322
2/28/13 6:02:06 AM  bootpd[90654]   DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,d4:9a:20:d5:7a:9c <labmac36>
2/28/13 6:02:06 AM  bootpd[90654]   ACK sent labmac36 192.168.6.67 pktsize 322
2/28/13 6:02:14 AM  bootpd[90654]   DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,d4:9a:20:d5:7a:9c <labmac36>
2/28/13 6:02:14 AM  bootpd[90654]   ACK sent labmac36 192.168.6.67 pktsize 322
2/28/13 6:02:15 AM  bootpd[90654]   DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,d4:9a:20:d5:7a:9c <labmac36>
2/28/13 6:02:15 AM  bootpd[90654]   ACK sent labmac36 192.168.6.67 pktsize 322
2/28/13 7:41:52 AM  bootpd[92105]   DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,d4:9a:20:d5:7a:9c <labmac36>
2/28/13 7:41:52 AM  bootpd[92105]   ACK sent labmac36 192.168.6.67 pktsize 322
2/28/13 7:41:59 AM  bootpd[92105]   DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,d4:9a:20:d5:7a:9c <labmac36>
2/28/13 7:41:59 AM  bootpd[92105]   ACK sent labmac36 192.168.6.67 pktsize 322
```

Contents of /var/db/dhcpclient/leases for en0 interface on labmac36

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>IPAddress</key>
    <string>192.168.6.67</string>
    <key>LeaseLength</key>
    <integer>85536</integer>
    <key>LeaseStartDate</key>
    <date>2013-02-28T12:41:58Z</date>
    <key>PacketData</key>
    <data>
    AgEGAPomDwgAAAAAAAAAAMCoBkPAqAYKAAAAANSaINV6nAAAAAAAAAAAAABucy5zaGls
    bGluZ3RvbnNjaG9vbC5jb20AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABjglNjNQEFNgTAqAYKMwQAAU4g
    AQT///8AAwTAqAYBBgTAqAYKDxVzaGlsbGluZ3RvbnNjaG9vbC5jb213FxFzaGlsbGlu
    Z3RvbnNjaG9vbANjb20A/w==
    </data>
    <key>RouterHardwareAddress</key>
    <data>
    AB2qgZwc
    </data>
    <key>RouterIPAddress</key>
    <string>192.168.6.1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```